# Magento multiselect limit to number of selected options

Tags: php, magento

Does magento have some sort of built in limit to the number of options one can select in a multiselect field?

I need to select >50 options on a regular basis except it doesn't seem to be able to select more than 41 out of the array of option ID's I pass to it.

The code I'm using is like this... Where $valueIds is an array of option ID's

```
if($valuesIds){

                $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku',$trimmedSKU);
                if($product){
                try {
                $product->setData($this->attrCode, $valuesIds);
                $product->save();
                } catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
                    echo $e->getMessage();
                }
                }else{

                    echo "SKU $trimmedSKU Does Not Match any Product";

                }
            }
```

When this is being processed only the first 41 items in the array are selected, everything after that is ignored. Does anybody know why this might be?

Comment: As for i know there is no rule for limits.you have to check your code for fetching options.

Answer (score 2):

Most probably it's a limitation of MySQL. If the attribute you use has the `backend_type` `varchar` then limit is 255 characters.
If that is the case, try to change the `backend_type` to `text`, but back-up first. You might lose the values that already exist.
You may need to move them from table `catalog_product_entity_varchar` to `catalog_product_entity_text`.

Comment: Is there any easy way to change the backend type? can it be done in the admin area or is it a db change?

Comment: You can change it from the db. Identify the attribute in the table `eav_attribute` and change the field `backend_type`. But like I said, you may lose the existing values.

Comment: I've just tried this and I've come across the problem that it no longer saves the selected attributes at all now... not in the varchar table or the text table